# Radial SVM Classifcation wtih Cross Validation and Tuning in R

Tags: r, svm, cross-validation, r-caret

I am in the process of creating a Radial SVM Classification model and I would to perform 5-fold CV on it and tune it. I have seen how others do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461476/svm-with-cross-validation-in-r-using-caret) and [followed these instructions](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#model-training-and-parameter-tuning). However, my code does not want to implement my tuning grid. Also, I do not understand why I cannot get Accuracy or an F1 value when I train the model explicitly.

**With 5-fold CV**

```
library(caret)
set.seed(500)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                      number = 5,
                      repeats = 3, 
                      classProb=T,
                      summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
                     )
sigma<-c(2^-15,2^-13,2^-11,2^-9,2^-7,2^-5,2^-3,2^-1,2^1,2^2,2^3)
C<-c(2^-5,2^-3,2^-1,2^1,2^2,2^3,2^5,2^7,2^9,2^11,2^13)
tuninggrid<-data.frame(expand.grid(sigma,C))

mod <- train(x = iris[-5], y=iris$Species,
             method = "svmRadial", 
             trControl = ctrl,
             metric=c('ROC'),
             tunegrid=tuninggrid
```

The results are simply sigma was held constant. Why does it not use my tuning grid?

Secondly, when I adjust the metric from `'ROC'` to `'Accuracy'`, it says Accuracy is not available. This I understand is because of my summaryFunction in `trainControl.` If I remove it, then I can get Accuracy, but not ROC. Ultimately, I would like both and an F1 value, but I cannot find documentation on this. How would I write something to give me both at the same time?

Lastly, the output from `train()`. To get the weights, it is just using mod$finalModel@coef correct?

Comment: At first blush have you looked at str(mod) and summary(mod) ?

Comment: Also, my recollection of how this works is that  you have requested that the CV be done 5 times, not that you have created 5-fold CV.

Comment: Ohh. So how would you fix that then?

Comment: If you don't get an answer I'll try and give more details later.  However, if you google the relevant terms you will find a lot of caret documentation exists online.  Honestly that is, for your own edification, the best procedure.

Comment: As much as I have reviewed it, I am still troubling to understand it.

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#model-training-and-parameter-tuning) and all your questions should be answered. If still in doubt post an update to the question.

Comment: I updated the question after doing the reading on it to make it more clear and specific. Not all of my questions are answered but heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few small errors in your code:

1. If you want to use area under the ROC as metric, you need to specify `twoClassSummary` as you did, but your response variable should also be binary. For example:

   ```
   train(..., y = factor(ifelse(iris$Species=="setosa", "setosa", "other")), ...)
   ```
2. If you want to use accuracy as metric, use `defaultSummary` instead of `twoClassSummary`
3. If you `View(tuninggrid)` you will see that its column names are Var1 and Var2, whereas they should be C and sigma. You can fix its definition:

   ```
   tuninggrid <- expand.grid(sigma=sigma,C=C)
   ```
4. There is a typo in the call to `train(...)`: correct argument name is `tuneGrid` (R is case sensitive)

Fixing these will solve your problem: `View(mod$results)`

EDIT: if you want to optimize the accuracy (computed in `defaultSummary`) but also display the AUROC (from `twoClassSummary`) and/or F measure (from `prSummary`), you can define your own metric function which combines all and use it in trainControl:

```r
combinedSummary <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
  c(
    defaultSummary(data, lev, model),
    twoClassSummary(data, lev, model), 
    prSummary(data, lev, model)
    )
}
```

Comment: How would you get Accuracy and ROC and F1 all at once though? Or can you only do one or the other?

Comment: The objective function that you optimize should be one-dimensional. Otherwise, how would you decide which option is best between (Acc=0.81, AUC=0.95, F1=0.87) and (Acc=0.95, AUC=0.87, F1=0.81) ? So the best is to choose one or the other, and if really necessary you can still build your own performance metric.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. So if I wanted to maximize accuracy I would not define the twoClassSummary part. But then I am assuming there must be ways to get the AUC and F1?

Comment: Now I understand your comment better... I've edited the answer

Comment: To follow up, the metric that I select in train is 'AUC', not 'ROC' and within `View(mod$results)`, I assume I am using the AUC value, not the ROC value that it produces?

Comment: Indeed, `metric='ROC'` computes and optimises the AUC (which is the area under the ROC curve)

Comment: I tested both, as in with `metric='ROC'` and then `'AUC'` and got the same results after I posted this, just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Nice, thanks: I didn't know you could use value 'AUC' as alias for 'ROC'